# Tridion still uses c:\windows\temp folder at publish time

Tags: publishing, configuration, content-delivery

our Tridion installation has been configured to have all its temporary folders pointed to a dedicated folder on our D-drive (configured in the MMC of Tridion).

However, it seems that during a publishing action the "C:\Windows\TEMP" folder is still used, by either the CMS/publisher or by CD components (impossible to tell as it concerns a development machine hosting all features on one box).

I couldn't find any other config file to override this location, and the client's virus software needs to scan the windows\temp folder. Imaging 100 users publishing items; the CPU/virus scan/... will go crazy. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart all of the relevant Windows services after modifying your configs?

Comment: I wonder if this is just the `TEMP` folder for the user running the publisher service (default is SYSTEM, it would make sense if that's the case). Will try to check it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the deployer incoming location to something else than c:\windows\temp. Example (cd_deployer_conf.xml):

```
<Location Path="d:\tridion\incoming" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
```

Also, if you have anything that is deployed to FileSystem than you need to change the FileSystemTransactionFolder (temporary folder used to ensure FileSystem transactionality). Example (cd_storage_conf.xml):

```
<Storages TempFileSystemTransactionLocation="d:\tridion\myTemp">
```

If those two paths do not help then you might need to send the following Java System Property: `-Dtridion.licenselock.dir="d:\tridion\license\temp"`. This is a temporary path needed for the license validation process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: <Storages TempFileSystemTransactionLocation="d:\tridion\myTemp"> works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There are several places where this might be configured. (This may differ between versions, so please specify which version you are on.)

To start with, in the management snap-in you have the following:

```
Publisher Settings -> Root storage folder
General Settings -> Temporary Path
```

I don't think the default Tridion.ContentManager.config file has any reference to temp directories, but it's worth a check.

Then you have the CD configuration files, for example cd_deployer_conf.xml - on a development box, there may be several examples of these for different web applications, and don't forget the logback configuration files.

Of course, it's always possible that there's some Tridion code that doesn't use a configuration setting for this, in which case you'd need to contact support, but I'd think these days that should be unlikely. (I have a vague memory that the tcm protocol handler used to use the temp directory, but that's a long time ago.)

For something that's occurring during publishing, don't forget your own implementation. What about your templates, events system code etc.

To analyse this kind of problem, I would highly recommend the [Process Monitor utility from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). You should be able to isolate exactly which process the writes are coming from.

Comment: it's a 2011 SP1 setup. All config files + management snap-in are configured correctly; I'll try procmon and eventually official support in case of no results. Thanks

Comment: It's the cd_deployer.exe that keeps on using the system default TEMP folder. Will contact support; keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: if your configuration contains an error it will use the default config file in the tridion / config folder. so make sure the config is correct, and make sure you restart the cd_deployer service. and just in case restart iss and com+